# wchar_t to unsigned char conversion

Tags: c++, c, unicode, ansi

I have a code that implements the following:

```
unsigned char charStr; //this var can only take a value either 0, 1, or 2
WCHAR wcharStr;
...
charStr = wcharStr - '0';
...
```

I am aware of the fact that you might lose some data (from 16-bit to 8-bit) while making a conversion from Unicode (wchar_t data type) to ANSI (unsigned char). However, can someone explain why substracting '0' make this conversion right ?

Comment: It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: immibis, ok, so what does it do ?

Comment: It depends on the context. Usually you do `c-'0'` when c is the a digit and you wan to get the representation of the digit.

Comment: thanks Pablo, I think the case you bring up is exactly the one I mean. Sorry for my lack of knowledge (I am a newbie), but what do you mean with "getting the representation of the digit"

Comment: None of those are strings, why are they named as such?

Comment: I made them up so. The real var names are much longer and they are of little value for the discussion

Comment: Are we talking about only 3 cases, 0,1 and 2?

Comment: @Killzone, yes it's only about  these 3 cases

Comment: Step 1 please stop thinking of `wchar_t` as being "Unicode", or of `char` as being "ANSI".

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit thanks, I will keep it in mind. Anything else to comment on the question ?

Comment: @ekremer when I talk about the representation of a digit, I mean this: 1 is a digit, it's representation is `'1'` which is a numeric constant with value 49 (the value is defined by the ASCII table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C and C++ language standard requires that the encodings for the digits from `0` to `9` be consecutive.  Therefore, subtracting `'4' - '0'`, for example, will get you `4`.

This is not actually required for `wchar_t`, but in the real world, your compiler will map that to Unicode, either UTF-16 on Windows or UCS-4 elsewhere.  The first 128 code points of Unicode are the same as ASCII.  You’re not compiling this code on the one modern, real-world compiler that uses a non-ASCII character set (IBM’s Z-series mainframes, which default to Code Page 1047 for backward compatibility), so your compiler converts your `wchar_t` and `char` to some integral type, probably 32 bits wide, subtracts, and gets a digit value.  It then stores that in a variable of type `unsigned char`, which is a mistake because it’s actually the ASCII value of an unprintable control character.

This code is not correct.  If you want to convert from `wchar_t` to `char`, you should use either `codecvt` from the STL or `wcrtomb()` from the C standard library.  There is also a `wctob()` that converts to a single byte if and only if that’s possible.  Set your locale before you use them.

If you’re sure that your `wchar_t` holds Unicode, that your `unsigned char` holds Latin-1, and your values are within range, however, you can simply cast the `wchar_t` value to `(unsigned char)`.  Another approach, if you know you have a digit, is to write `(charStr - L'0') + '0'`.

Comment: Funny things is that my man page of `wctob` says: *Never use this function.  It cannot help you in writing internationalized programs.*

Comment: @Pablo The justification for that on Linux is, "Internationalized programs must never distinguish single-byte and multibyte characters." So, this code is already breaking that advice anyway. But convert to a multi-byte string for better portability.

Comment: To make life extra fun, IBM’s Z-series mainframes also use a 2-byte wchar_t.